# Manipulating form input values after submission causes multiple instances

Tags: forms, model, yii, save

I'm building a form with Yii that updates two models at once.
The form takes the inputs for each model as $modelA and $modelB and then handles them separately as described here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

This is all good.  The difference I have to the example is that $modelA (documents) has to be saved and its ID retrieved and then $modelB has to be saved including the ID from $model A as they are related.

There's an additional twist that $modelB has a file which needs to be saved.

My action code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['Documents'], $_POST['DocumentVersions']))
    {
        $modelA->attributes=$_POST['Documents'];
        $modelB->attributes=$_POST['DocumentVersions'];


        $valid=$modelA->validate();
        $valid=$modelB->validate() && $valid;


        if($valid)
        {

            $modelA->save(false); // don't validate as we validated above.
            $newdoc = $modelA->primaryKey; // get the ID of the document just created

            $modelB->document_id = $newdoc;         // set the Document_id of the DocumentVersions to be $newdoc
            // todo: set the filename to some long hash

            $modelB->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($modelB,'file');       
            // finish set filename
            $modelB->save(false);

            if($modelB->save()) {
                $modelB->file->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/'.$modelB->file);
                }

            $this->redirect(array('projects/myprojects','id'=>$_POST['project_id']));
        }
    }
    ELSE {

    $this->render('create',array(
        'modelA'=>$modelA,
        'modelB'=>$modelB,
        'parent'=>$id,
        'userid'=>$userid,
        'categories'=>$categoriesList
    ));
    }
```

You can see that I push the new values for 'file' and 'document_id' into $modelB.  What this all works no problem, but... each time I push one of these values into $modelB I seem to get an new instance of $modelA.  So the net result, I get 3 new documents, and 1 new version.  The new version is all linked up correctly, but the other two documents are just straight duplicates.
I've tested removing the $modelB update steps, and sure enough, for each one removed a copy of $modelA is removed (or at least the resulting database entry).
I've no idea how to prevent this.

UPDATE....

As I put in a comment below, further testing shows the number of instances of $modelA depends on how many times the form has been submitted.  Even if other pages/views are accessed in the meantime, if the form is resubmitted within a short period of time, each time I get an extra entry in the database.  If this was due to some form of persistence, then I'd expect to get an extra copy of the PREVIOUS model, not multiples of the current one.  So I suspect something in the way its saving, like there is some counter that's incrementing, but I've no idea where to look for this, or how to zero it each time.

Some help would be much appreciated.
thanks

JMB

Comment: I was about to post the same question :) I was browsing for yii questions to see if someone else posted this :) I'm having the exact same problem. Model A form + Model B form in same _form.php and Model B needs the ID from Model A. I will have a look to the link you posted to see If I can solve my problem and help you with your current problem.

Comment: I would expect you get two instances of `$modelB` to one of `$modelA` since you save `$modelB` then doing it again in the if condition. However i can't understand why you are getting this weird result (3 copies of `$modelA` to one from `$modelB`?? Are you sure you don't have an `afterSave` method in `$modelB` !!

Comment: OK, some more debugging shows... the number of instances of model B seems to be based on the number of form submits, if I keep adding more documents one after the other, I get more and more instances of $modelA.  The models are reset at the top of the code with $modelA = new Documents and $modelB = new DocumentVersion.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement the same idea for my own project and my code don't pass the is($valid)   condition. Do we need to insert any sort or code on the form to allow the id from model A to be inserted on model B? In your code this $modelB->document_id = $newdoc; does the trick but i still can't pass the validation of models. In my case I'm trying 3 models ModelA, B and C and the primary key from A should go to modelB and modelC as well. Any ideas of what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had Ajax validation set to true.  This was calling the create action and inserting entries.  I don't fully get this, or how I could use ajax validation if I really wanted to without this effect, but... at least the two model insert with relationship works.

Thanks for the comments.
cheers
JMB